# Mysql group by column1,column2 'Desc\|asc' no error

Tags: mysql, mariadb

HOW comes when I run the below query there in no error. Note the DESC on the query.

```
select date(created) date,
       count(distinct some_id) subsccount,
       type
    from  sometable
    group by date,type DESC
    limit 5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MySQL documentation on [select syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) says:

> MySQL extends the GROUP BY clause so that you can also specify ASC and
>   DESC after columns named in the clause:
>
> ```
> SELECT a, COUNT(b) FROM test_table GROUP BY a DESC;
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's valid syntax

> Relying on implicit GROUP BY sorting (that is, sorting in the absence
>   of ASC or DESC designators) is deprecated. To produce a given sort
>   order, use explicit ASC or DESC designators for GROUP BY columns or
>   provide an ORDER BY clause.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html